# Create a modal line or benchmark

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I have some data the following, X is cycle in percentage, and Y is the quantity:

```
SampleID　X　　　　Y
1　　　　　0.52　　0.9720
1　　　　　0.66　　0.9760
1　　　　　0.67　　0.9760
1　　　　　0.69　　0.9952
2　　　　　0.21　　0.2564
...
```

And I tried to average the Y with same X value, such that I can draw a chart like this:
[image: 1st Draft]

Here is the data file: [Link to Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MUhIKWZPke_5U1_2Fa379QNkdLUHgc-Wo3H1s5zZ-dw/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true)

This chart not very ideal, I want to create a chart more like a curve, so that I may able to compare with other sample data.
But my problem is, I'm not sure what technique I should use, is there have any suggestion? I tried the linear regression, but not what I want, maybe I should have something like sigmoid?

Comment: If it weren't for that last dip you could fit $$y(x)=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\arctan(\alpha + \beta x)}{\pi} $$

Comment: Or $$ y(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\cos(\pi x)}{2} $$

Comment: @ja72 thanks for your answer, when I apply it, it really get the perfect s-curve, however, seems this formula ignore the original value for "y"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a quarter cycle occurs for every 0.88 of *x*. In addition *y* ranges from 0 to 1.00 approx. So you can try fitting $$ y(x) = Y \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\cos(\pi x/a)}{2} \right) $$

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I'm wanna draw a S-curve based on value of Y, but not calculated based on X only, so that if I have another set of Y, I may able to draw a different S-curve

Comment: You have to share your data in order to get a good answer. Maybe put in a text file and host it online somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I have save those data into google drive, hope it may help

Comment: See edits. This is best that can be done with a harmonic function.